# Image in GWT Button

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-mosaic

How do I add image to GWT Button or how do I use Mosaic's Buttons to add image. I can't figure out how to use [THIS](http://69.20.122.77/gwt-mosaic/Showcase.html#CwBasicButton) example in my code. What library do I need to add. I have Mosaic Library in my project and I can use it but the example that they have there does not work for me.

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried, and what is the result?

Comment: If you want to have image and text then I probably created what you want. I wrote a post on this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853042/creating-custom-button-in-gwt/2449019#2449019

Comment: GWT oficial sample:
http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomButton

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you just want to add an image to a normal GWT Button, then [PushButton](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PushButton.html) is the way to go:

```
PushButton pushButton = new PushButton(new Image("test.png"));
```

Answer (score 24):

PushButton does not have the same behavior, and you have a prettier solution than creating yourself an image tag :

```
Image img = new Image("whatever.jpg");
Button button = new Button();
button.getElement().appendChild(img.getElement());
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you this method.

```
Button editRow = new Button("Edit Row");
editRow.setHTML(("<img border='0' src='rowEdit.Png' />");
```

I have found the the PushButton appears to have a problem with calculating its x, y click point correctly, which the normal button does not have.

Answer (score 3):

Just use CSS and style in the image.  Something like this should make the image appear before the button text:

```
background-image: url("/yourimage.png");
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
height: 20px;
width:      20px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the HTML img tag inside the button as:

```
Button btn = new Button("<img src='image.png'/>");
```