# creating custom button in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, button, custom-controls

I am trying to do something pretty common with GWT - creating a button behavior with an image and a text by positioning the text on top of the image.

I have used the `HTML` widget but how can I make the text not selectable?

Answer (score 9):

I recently had the same need for a GWT button which allows to add image AND text. So I coded one myself since the already available implementations didn't work. I [wrote a post on my blog](http://juristr.com/blog/2010/03/gwt-button-with-image-and-text/) but I also copy the code here:

Here's the code for my custom button

```
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;

public class CustomButton extends Button {
    private String text;

    public CustomButton(){
        super();
    }

    public void setResource(ImageResource imageResource){
        Image img = new Image(imageResource);
        String definedStyles = img.getElement().getAttribute("style");
        img.getElement().setAttribute("style", definedStyles + "; vertical-align:middle;");
        DOM.insertBefore(getElement(), img.getElement(), DOM.getFirstChild(getElement()));
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        Element span = DOM.createElement("span");
        span.setInnerText(text);
        span.setAttribute("style", "padding-left:3px; vertical-align:middle;");

        DOM.insertChild(getElement(), span, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

**Usage with UiBinder XML definition**

```
...
<!-- ImageBundle definition -->
<ui:with field="res" type="com.sample.client.IDevbookImageBundle" />
...
<d:CustomButton ui:field="buttonSave" text="Save" resource="{res.save}"></d:CustomButton>
```

The screenshot of such a button:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to get rid of the text select cursor, or make the text completely unselectable?

To make it look like something clickable, you can use the cursor CSS rule.

```
.widget_style {cursor: pointer;}
```

Actually making it unselectable is not well supported from what I understand. It is in the CSS3 specs with user-select.

```
.widget_style {user-select:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Button-Widget and call the setHTML() function.
You could use this code:

```
public class Custombutton extends Button {
    public CustomButton(String text, String img) {
        this.setHTML(text + "<br><img src=\"" + img + "\">");
    }     
}
```

You just have to provide the text and the img url when you create the button.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the CustomButton class of gwt?

here is the link:

http://projectpossibility.org/projects/word_prediction/gwt-linux-1.4.60/doc/javadoc/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CustomButton.html

Comment: Please provide links to current documentation and from official sources: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CustomButton.html

Comment: Oh i am sorry i though it was the new one.

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

A class that allows the addition of arbitrary widgets to a Button:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasWidgets;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class ButtonWithWidgets extends Button implements HasWidgets
{
    private ArrayList<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();

    @Override
    public void add(Widget w)
    {
        DOM.insertChild(getElement(), w.getElement(), widgets.size());
    }

    @Override
    public void clear()
    {
        for (Widget widget : widgets)
        {
            DOM.removeChild(getElement(), widget.getElement());
        }
        widgets.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Widget> iterator()
    {
        return widgets.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Widget w)
    {
        if (widgets.indexOf(w) != -1)
        {
            widgets.remove(w);
            DOM.removeChild(getElement(), w.getElement());
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

with UiBinder:

...

```
<customwidgets:ButtonWithWidgets>
    <g:Label>Whatever</g:Label>
    <g:Image url="etc.png"/>
</customwidgets:ButtonWithWidgets>
```