# How to put the Icons In the Center of the button in GXT

Tags: css, gwt, gwt2, gxt

Hi i am working on GXT

i have a button with an Icon.

I want to put the Icon in center.

Currently it looks like this.

[image]

the icon of the button is in left (because of IconAlign.LEFT).

I want it in center. But there is nothing like IconAlign.CENTER

If any one has an idea what to add in code.Please share

**code**

```
button.setIconAlign(IconAlign.LEFT);
button.setIcon(Resources.INSTANCE.modify());
button.setStyleName("project-Button");
```

**CSS**

```
.project-Button {
    color: Black;
    border: thin outset #FF6600;
    font-family: Courier New, Century Gothic, Times New Roman, Verdana, Arial;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: White;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

thank you in advance

---

updated

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {

    public Resources INSTANCE = GWT.create(Resources.class);

     @Source("Images/modify.png")
     ImageResource modify();
}
```

Comment: Depending on where you're putting that CSS rule it might not be applied due to obfuscation. You might need to use a `ClientBundle` as you're doing with the icon.

Comment: I am using clientBundle .. Plz chk the updated areai question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used this. and itis working fine.

```
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
background-position:30% 70%;
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431020/gwt-custom-button-with-icon-above-text) top answer is a bit of a hack but it should work.

Basically you can set the HTML within the button like this:

```java
Button button = new Button();
String html = "...";
button.setHTML(html);
```

Within the HTML string you can put a `<div>` with the image.

There's more than likely a better way though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need exactly this long button, with image in center and text on the right of image?
I mean, Can you use it with image on Top and text under them? Like here [EXT GWT Showcase button](http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#buttons)

Comment: yes i want long buttons with the text and Image in the center.
I am using GXT and i checked http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:buttons but couldn't find anything. I u have any Idea how to do this , please share.

Comment: Hey, Looks like I find the easiest way if you know some image redactors. You can create a wide "Icon (Image) with text on the right". F.e.  Button btn = new com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.button.Button(""); btn.setScale(Style.ButtonScale.MEDIUM);
btn.setIconAlign(Style.IconAlign.TOP);
                    btn.setIcon(IconHelper.create("images//image_with_text.png", 120,22));

Comment: this gives me the icon on the top of the Text not like Button(center(left(Icon),Text))

Answer (score 0):

You could change the style like this :

```
.x-btn-text-icon .x-btn-text {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: 0 none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 86px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0 none;
  font: normal 11px arial,tahoma,verdana,helvetica;
  color: #333;
  background: transparent;
  background-position: 0 center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 32px;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that with ExtJs there is a `iconAlign:'center'`, so I wonder if you could use a `JsObject` with the right JSON description in your java code ......

Answer (score 0):

use `.center {margin:0, auto; }`

if you use "background-position:30% 70%;" it is problem in resolution change or large size monitors. when we design UI we make sure about cross resolution also.

happy designing by css